# Android WebView, show pdf file via Google Viewer with passing cookies

Tags: android, pdf, cookies, webview

I'm using this code to get pdf-file from Internet and show it in WebView. The problem is that I need to pass cookies to get access to that file, and I should use Google Viewer to show that file in WebView.

So, it looks like Google Viewer can't handle my cookies.
Is it possible to show file via Google Viewer and auth cookies?
Code:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

CookieManager manager = CookieManager.getInstance();
manager.setAcceptCookie(true);
manager.setCookie(url,cookie);//PHPSESSID=blablablablablablabla;timeZone=+03:00

mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
mWebView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + url);
```

As a result, I get "Whoops! There was a problem displaying this image." message. If I trying to access url directly without Google Viewer prefix, I am getting request for file downloading. Any suggestions?

I also trying to make code like

```
url = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + url;
manager.setCookie(url,cookie);
...
mWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

but in that case WebView just remains empty.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same problem too, Did you get any answer?

Comment: @SimonChius Hello! No, i abandoned idea of showing pdf in WebView and now I just downloading it to show in another application.

Comment: Hi, I have found a solution for this, You have to Encode that URL. It works fine for me.

Comment: @SimonChius Could you please share the code snippet? I am getting the blank screen when I tried this.

Answer (score 0):

you have to encode the Url and pass it to web view it will work fine. `mWebView.loadUrl(URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8"))`
This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use https:// instead http:// for docs.google.com/

```
url = "https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + url;
```