# How to show excel, docs, pdf.. with passing cookies in webview Android

Tags: android, excel, pdf, cookies, webview

I'm trying to show **excel** file(online) in a webview with passing cookies, but only get a blank white page.

It works fine for **txt** file, so maybe passing the cookie is not the problem.

```
webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
webView.settings.setSupportZoom(true)
webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

val cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance()
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true)
cookieManager.setCookie(url,cookie)
cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true)
cookieManager.flush()
webView.loadUrl(url)
```

I also tried this([Android WebView, show pdf file via Google Viewer with passing cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37027834/android-webview-show-pdf-file-via-google-viewer-with-passing-cookies))  but it didn't work.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: A WebView cannot display pdf, doc and excel files. Only html.

Comment: @blackapps Thank you for your answer. Is there any way to solve this?